# display flex causing text to be appearing in other div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am facing this issue in mobile devices only. the text in the right section of the below code is appearing over the image in the left side.Please check this fiddle :

[check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nq7g37zt/)

```
<div id="main-class" style="border: 1px solid;width:600px;">
<div class='a_class'>
<div id="wrapper-inner" style="display:flex;;overflow:hidden;">
<div style="padding:10px;"><img src="http://shop.wwe.com/on/demandware.static/-/Sites/default/dw29757933/images/slot/landing/superstar-landing/Superstar-Category_Superstar_562x408_theRock.png" 
style="width:80px;height:80px"></div>
 <div style="text-align: left;">
 <span style="display:block;">Javascript is fun</span>
 <span style="">Programming language</span>
 <div class="space" style="height:5px"></div>
 <div style="font-size:12px;color:#90949c;">If this text is too large then   this is casuing the whole section in the right side to be appear over the left   image. this issue is occuring in mobile devices only. In desktop, its working f  ine </div>
</div>

</div><!--wrapper-inner -->
</div><!--a_class -->
</div><!--main-class -->
```

[image: please check this screenshot from iphone 6plus]

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. You haven't even specified which phone and which mobile browser.

Comment: @SergChernata : you can check the fiddle in any mobile. By looking into it, you will get exactly what my issue is. :)

Comment: I did. No issues.

Comment: Can´t see a problem with current chrome in mobile mode... May you provide used browser and maybe a screenshot?

Comment: @SergChernata I have attached screenshot. please check. the text in appearing even more left in many phones.

Comment: @MarcelSchmid  I have attached screenshot. please check. the text in appearing even more left in many phones.

Comment: inline styles, uuugh, I hate debugging in line styles - not sure if this has changed anything as I can't replicate the error either, but give this a go: https://jsfiddle.net/nq7g37zt/2/

Answer (score 0):

Okay I just got what you want.

You define in your first line a width of 600px, so ofc your box will always have 600px width, even on mobile phones. Use "**max-width**" instead and you should be fine.

And if you plan to do more things with html/css I would realy recomment that you take some time and read into css selectors/classes and separate your css and html then!

Comment: Still doesn't work. the text is still appearing over the image. I don't think this is due to the width.

Comment: It´s realy hard to tell since I can´t reproduce your bug. With using the max-width the text adepts perfectly for me for any size of the browser and also with the "mobile-simulating-mode"